# How to fix Promise {<pending>} when trying to play an audio file on keydown event in Gatsby framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, gatsby

I'm attempting to add a HTML/Javascript drumkit I've made to my Gatsby site. Currently, no sounds play when keys are pressed, and the promise returned from audio.play() hangs at "pending".

I've gotten this to work with basic HTML/JS as well as with a standard React app. But when trying to incorporate it into my Gatsby site, I run into the below issues with the returned promises, and no sounds play.

```
[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

The git repo for the whole Gatsby site is here (currently only dev build) https://github.com/mfuller22/FullerStackProgramming

The directory for the specific page I'm having trouble with is here https://github.com/mfuller22/FullerStackProgramming/tree/master/src/pages/Projects/DrumKit

I will add my React code in a few hours. I don't currently have it with me.

```
componentDidMount() {    
  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown.bind(this));
}

handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === parseInt(this.props.id, 10))
    this.playSound()
}

playSound = () => {
  const audio = document.getElementById('sound'+this.props.id);
  const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${this.props.id}"]`);
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  console.log(audio)
  var playPromise = audio.play();
  console.log(playPromise)
  playPromise.catch(error => {
    audio.play();
  });
  key.classList.add('playing');
};    

render() {
  const { id, letter, sound } = this.props

  return (
    <div
      id={'key'+id}
      data-key={id}
      onClick={() => this._playSound}
      onKeyDown={() => this._playSound}
      onTransitionEnd={() => this._onTransitionEnd}
      className="key">
      <kbd>{letter}</kbd>
      <span className="sound">{sound}</span>
      <audio id={'sound'+id}>
        <source src={sound} type="audio/wav" />
      </audio>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would expect the promise to be returned with a status of resolved, but currently the promise status is pending, and the promise value is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure that `this` in `playSound()` is correct? It appears not to be. You probably want to pass `this.props.id` from the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Roamer. Let me see if I understand your suggestion - are you recommending adding the argument `this.props.id` into `this.playSound()`? If it provides any consolation, when I `console.log(audio)` in the `playSound` function, it returns the correct audio element that is intended to be played. That would presumably tell me that the correct things are being passed from the event handler. But maybe I'm wrong? I'm still very new to React and somewhat new to JavaScript.

Comment: I take your word for it though I can't see why that would be so.

Comment: `this.playSound.call(this);` would be safer.

Comment: This is an example of the audio element attempting to be played whether I keep it the way it was, or if I implement your preferred method:  `<audio id="sound65"><source src="clap" type="audio/wav"></audio>`. The source comes from imported audio files at the beginning of the reactjs file. Though the same issue occurs if I instead make the src reference a dynamic path to a specific audio file in the project directory depending on the key pressed.

In either event, still running into the promise pending issue

Comment: The promise is just pending at the point where you log it. You shouldn't be interested in the promise's state *per se*, just whether its success or error callback fires. Try chaining `playPromise.then(...).catch(...)` with `console.log()` in each. One or other should fire.

Comment: Good suggestion, Roamer. I'm working on this, but in doing so have noticed that I'm getting two logs from `console.log(audio)` in the `playSound` function. Seems as though it's being called from two locations which could be the source of the problem, though I'm not sure how that would be the case.

Comment: Mmm, odd. Could be that `componentDidMount()` gets executed twice, or possibly some kind of event bubbling issue.

Comment: It looks like both might be the case? Putting logs both in `componentDidMount` and in `handlekeyDown` shows they are executing twice... maybe this has to do with what I'm doing in my index.js and App.js files?

Comment: Seems unlikely to be both. If it was, then you might expect `componentDidMount` to fire twice and  `handlekeyDown` to fire four times.

Comment: Seems like it's componentDidMount that's firing twice... and again, in the react application of this that doesn't happen. So wondering why it would happen in Gatsby but not React? My react drumkit is almost a replica of this one for reference: https://github.com/JaviEzpeleta/react-keyboard-drum-set

Comment: It may be a known thing. Take a browse through Gatsby's Issues.

Comment: So in looking through reasons why `componentDidMount` would fire twice, there were a few scattered throughout Gatsby's issues and on SO. Some were related to including state changed within `componentDidMount` which causes a re-render, or some mentioned that this happens in developer mode but not on production builds.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it with my file/code organization. Given all that I've learned looking into this over the past week, I decided to revert back to my initial plan, which was simply to include the original HTML and JS files used to create the DrumKit instead of transitioning them to React components. This can be done pretty easily by creating and exporting a react constant where the html is returned within. And in the `<body>` of the HTML, use `react-helmet` and a `<script>` tag to include JS. My original problem I think was my paths to the audio files were wrong. I imported them as a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up dealing with this by, instead of moving everything over to React components, keeping my original HTML and JS code as they were and including them like below (making sure to `import` the audio files and referencing the import as the src):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { withPrefix, Link } from "gatsby"

import Clap from "./sounds/clap.wav"
import Hihat from "./sounds/hihat.wav"
import Kick from "./sounds/kick.wav"
import Openhat from "./sounds/openhat.wav"
import Boom from "./sounds/boom.wav"
import Ride from "./sounds/ride.wav"
import Snare from "./sounds/snare.wav"
import Tom from "./sounds/tom.wav"
import Tink from "./sounds/tink.wav"

const Javascript30 = ({location }) => {
    if (location.pathname === ("/Projects/DrumKit/Javascript30/")){
        require("./style.css")
    }
    else{
        console.log("failed to load css")
    }

    return (
        <html>
            <body>
                <Helmet>
                    <script src={withPrefix('script.js')} type="text/javascript"></script>
                </Helmet>

                <div>
                    <button className="button" id="record">Record</button><br></br>
                    <button className="button" id="stop">Stop Recording</button><br></br>
                    <button className="button" id="play">Playback</button><br></br>
                </div>

                <div className="keys">
                    <div data-key="65" class="key">
                        <kbd>A</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">clap</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="83" class="key">
                        <kbd>S</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">hihat</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="68" class="key">
                        <kbd>D</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">kick</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="70" class="key">
                        <kbd>F</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">openhat</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="71" class="key">
                        <kbd>G</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">boom</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="72" class="key">
                        <kbd>H</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">ride</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="74" class="key">
                        <kbd>J</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">snare</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="75" class="key">
                        <kbd>K</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">tom</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="76" class="key">
                        <kbd>L</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">tink</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <audio data-key="65" src={Clap} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="83" src={Hihat} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="68" src={Kick} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="70" src={Openhat} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="71" src={Boom} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="72" src={Ride} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="74" src={Snare} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="75" src={Tom} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
                <audio data-key="76" src={Tink} preload="auto" crossOrigin="anonymous"></audio>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
};

export default Javascript30;
```